# When reviewing poor posts with comments, what's the proper course of action?

Tags: discussion, review

I've just failed a test in the review queue: There was a post of poor quality (the answer being essentially a link) and there was already a comment suggesting to expand the answer.

My course of action was to upvote the comment and give the poster the chance to comment. However, the test told me that I should have proposed a deletion or something.

Should one take a harsher course of action than to believe in the good will of the poster?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should base your judgment on what you see, not on what you hope to see in the future.

You can believe in good will of the poster *and* recommend deletion at the same time. There is no contradiction here. A post may be contributed in good faith yet be below par for the site.

Also, deletion does not close the door to improvement. If a post is deleted from review by six "recommend deletion" votes (which happens in the majority of cases, given how rare 20K deletion votes are), it can be restored by the author with one click on "undelete" — hopefully after they edited it into better shape.